# How to make all items invisible other than the one I clicked in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview items have additional information that is revealed by a click 
`p0.itemView.notes.visibility = VISIBLE` the problem is that I don't know how to make it GONE when another item is clicked.

I have tried setting it to GONE in the onBindViewHolder this result to a big mess where the VISIBLE stopped working and bugs etc.

kotlin

```
p0.itemView.notes.visibility = VISIBLE
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

I just need make the clicked item with additional info  VISIBLE and then GONE when another item is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold currently visible item. When you click another item, make visibility of previous item gone and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
p0.itemView.notes.visibility = VISIBLE
if (previousVisibleItem != null) {
   previousVisibleItem.visibility  = GONE
}

previousVisibleItem = p0.itemView.notes
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: How and where should I declare previousVisibleItem ? inside oonBindViewHolder like val previousVisibleItem2 : TextView ?

Comment: Define as a global variable in adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Set its width and height to zero to its row Using the LinearLayout params.

Comment: The problem is not setting it to gone, the problem is seting it to gone when another item is clicked.